# Draw HTML5 Canvas pulse line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Hey guys I've been trying to wrap my head around the HTML5 Canvas animation but failed miserably I wanted to achieve the below figure by animating this custom shape in an interval of 10 seconds.

I've pretty much screwed the math of it so I ended up just writing every lineTo statement manually, tried Paul Irish's requestAnimationFrame at the end to animate the line but no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated, here is 
    `the`[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LKSGL/145/)

Thanks guys

[image]

Comment: You can substitute all your lineTo code with `for(x = 1; x <= 6; x++){a = (x % 2)? canvas.width/6 : 0;b = (x % 2)? 0 : canvas.width/6;ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/6 * x, canvas.height/2 + b);ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/6 * x, canvas.height/2 + a);}` http://jsfiddle.net/wgy72/

Comment: Thanks @Jugale that will help a lot, any idea why isn't the animation working?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to animate - do you want each line to draw separately after an interval?

Comment: `draw()` is definitely being called every interval (added an alert to test this) - you can't tell it is because you're not changing any values each time it is called: you're just drawing the same shape again

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically needing a function that returns only 2 values--high and low.

Here's a function that returns only low/high values based on a period and oscillation values:

```
// squared wave

// p = period (how long it takes the wave to fully complete and begin a new cycle)
// o = oscillation (change in wave height)

function squareY(x) {
    return( (x%p)<o?o:0 );
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/A69ZV/

[image]

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth=3;

        var p=30;    // period
        var o=15;   // oscillation
        var fps = 60;
        var n=0;
        animate();
        function animate() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                // Drawing code goes here
                n+=1.5;
                if(n>300){
                    n=0;
                }
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.beginPath();
                for(var x=0;x<n;x++){
                    var y=squareY(x);
                    ctx.lineTo(x,y+50);
                }
                ctx.stroke();        

            }, 1000 / fps);
        }

        // squared sine
        function squareY(x) {
            return( (x%p)<o?o:0 );
        }

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that's exactly what I want, except that I call the animate function onclick event, each time it's called the animation speed increases the double instead of just redrawing, I also don't know how to stop the animation when it's done

Comment: `n` determines how far the animation will go rightward on the x-axis.  So if you want the animation to stop if n>300 just replace requestAnimationFrame(animate) with if(n<=300){requestAnimationFrame(animate);} To restart the animation clear the canvas plus: n=0; animate();  Cheers!

Comment: Here's a Fiddle of how to stop, resume and restart the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/F8Xyf/  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

It's not moving cause you are basically not moving anything - the same shape is drawn to the same position each iteration.

Here is a modified version which animates the pulse to the left (adjust `dlt` to change speed):

### [Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/LKSGL/146/)

```
var segX = canvas.width / 6;
var segY = canvas.height / 2;

function draw() {
    
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(0, segY);

    for(var i = dlt, h = true; i < canvas.width + segX; i += segX) {
        if (h) {
            ctx.lineTo(i, segY);
            ctx.lineTo(i, segY + segX);
        } else {
            ctx.lineTo(i, segY + segX);
            ctx.lineTo(i, segY);
        }
        h = !h;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    
    dlt--;
    if (dlt < -segX * 2) dlt = 0;
  
    requestAnimFrame(draw);
}
```

Comment: Man this is great but what I wanted is a little bit different, I wanted to animate the actual drawing of each line if you know what I mean.

Also I noticed that as I call the function again the speed increases, I was intending to use it on a button click event, when clicked the drawing will clear the stage and start over